# A question about dual licensing

Tags: licensing

I have decided to release my software with two licenses. At the same time I want this to be open-source. So how would I dual license? Which licenses do I pick?

I want one license to be very similar to GPL as long as the user uses it for non-commercial projects. The other license would be a commercial license (the user has to pay) so that the user can use it in commercial projects (doesn't matter whether it is proprietary or not for the commercial license).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha provides a good example of the dual licensing model in practice. It sounds like your goals are similar theirs. They have options of GPL and a proprietary Commercial License. It seems like a pretty good setup really. If folks want to use your product as a competitive advantage in their business they have to pay for it.

- [Licensing Overview](http://www.sencha.com/products/license.php)
- [Dual Licensing Model](http://www.sencha.com/company/dual.php)
- [Sencha Commercial Software License Agreement](http://www.sencha.com/store/js/license.php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see they use GPL for their open source license. Doesn't GPL allow commercial usage? This can be a problem if a user wants the resell the software without you getting any share.

Comment: GPL allows commercial usage as long as whoever is using your product publishes the source code of the project that they're using your product on, which isn't often :P

Comment: Well what would be the point of a commercial license? Is the commercial license for waiving the requirement of having to license under the GPL?

Comment: Exactly. The commercial license is so the customer won't have to license under GPL. The point is the customer picks a license based on their requirements.

Comment: Thank you for clearing all this up! Also, would I have to write a commercial license or is there one already available for me?

Comment: I don't know if there is a good canned Commercial license out there. But the Sencha license is probably a pretty good template to get started with.